# Why am I seeing a question mark with my uploaded video in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
VideoView videoView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    videoView=findViewById(R.id.video);

    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI((Uri.parse("android.resources://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.animation)));

    

}
```

}

my code
I am seeing a question mark with the video I have uploaded and its not playing in the app

Comment: Please, may you explaining more, I didn't get your question.

Comment: Please describe in details

Answer (score 0):

Try this once I saw in your code showing cant play this video.

```
  import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        VideoView videoView;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            videoView = findViewById(R.id.video);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +
                    R.raw.animation));
            videoView.start();
    
    
        }
    }
```